# How can audio be monitored on headphones during the recording?

Tags: audio, microphone, headphones, audio-recording, phone

I am recording audio with an external microphone that does have an extra headphone play-through jack, however I cannot hear the audio in the connected headphones. Some specific softwares like Audacity did have some internal settings relating to this, except I need a more universal solution; that is, even if I am recording on an android device.

---

*EDIT*
What I meant by universal solution, was maybe perhaps a certain setting I should be able to enable or something in any OS I'm using in general. Not as in an actual single solution that would possibly work cross-platform.

Even if there are different softwares for each OS needed to get the result, that would still be fine.

Comment: On what OS is this?

Comment: @MMM I tried on my windows 10 PC, on an IOS 12 Ipad, and a ColorOS 8 phone

Comment: The only way to do that cross-platform & completely latency-free is to intercept before the audio reaches the main device. Many audio interfaces can do this, but I don't know of one that would work across all those platforms. You may end up needing a small mixing 'desk' followed by DACs for each platform

Comment: @tetsujin I edited my post just hoping to clear things up a bit. Are there any softwares I could use to get around this? As in an an app, or actual installed Windows software etc.

Comment: I already outlined the closest thing to a universal solution - do it in hardware before reaching the device.

Answer (score 1):

This is a software- or hardware-specific setting, and isn't afforded by any OS that I know of. Perhaps there is a specialized Linux distribution that includes this feature, but—realistically—you're going to have to select DAW software on each platform that includes this feature (or—as @Tetsujin pointed out—do it through your hardware interface).

If you are looking for software recommendations, that is off-topic here and you should post on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).